# @font-face is not working in my css file

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, font-family

Hmm, ...can't figure this one out. My custom fonts aren't working in the css file. For some reason, the css file accepts the custom fonts *only* if they are placed in the system font folder. But, I want them in the project's "fonts" folder.

Project:

```
|-theProjectFolder
|-css
  |-style.css
|-fonts
  |-expansiva-bold.otf
|-views
  |-index.hbs
```

index.hbs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>My Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  .........
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
/* Custom Fonts */
@font-face {
  font-family: expansiva;
  src: url("../fonts/expansiva-bold.otf"); }
/****************/

.line1 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
  font-family: expansiva, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 56px;
}
```

So with this setup, all I get is the "Arial" font--no "expansiva". I looked around and found mention of converting the font to "web" font?? But, when I did that, there was no change either.

Comment: Did you add expansiva font to your computers fonts?

Comment: Check in your browser inspector if the font is being loaded (network tab on chrome), and also on your browser console if some errors, like 404, are coming up...

Answer (score 0):

Your font name for the custom font should be in quotes, try:
    font-family: 'expansiva';

If it's only loading when you give it a local path, it isn't properly on your server or your url is incorrect (yours looks fine though).

Comment: Sure enough, Chrome's Inspect is showing a 404 under: Network > Font. So I'm stuck now 'cause everything looks okay, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the "/fonts" folder was not reachable by the server. Since this is a Node/Express project, the solution was to add the fonts folder to Express (index.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');

const app = express();

hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);

app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/img'));
app.use('/fonts', express.static(__dirname + '/fonts')); // <--added

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));
app.get('/about', (req, res) => res.render('about'));
app.get('/contact', (req, res) => res.render('contact'));


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App listening at port 3000!')
});
```